# Copy the three newest files under one directory (recursively) to another specified directory

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using bash.

Suppose I have a log file directory `/var/myprogram/logs/`.

Under this directory I have many sub-directories and sub-sub-directories that include different types of log files from my program.

I'd like to find the three newest files (modified most recently), whose name starts with `2010`, under `/var/myprogram/logs/`, regardless of sub-directory and copy them to my home directory.

Here's what I would do manually
1. Go through each directory and do `ls -lt 2010*`
to see which files starting with `2010` are modified most recently.
2. Once I go through all directories, I'd know which three files are the newest. So I copy them manually to my home directory.

This is pretty tedious, so I wondered if maybe I could somehow pipe some commands together to do this in one step, preferably without using shell scripts?

I've been looking into `find`, `ls`, `head`, and `awk` that I might be able to use but haven't figured the right way to glue them together.

Let me know if I need to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
 find -type f -name '2010*' -printf "%C@\t%P\n" |sort -r -k1,1 |head -3 |cut -f 2-
```

This outputs a list of files prefixed by their last change time, sorts them based on that value, takes the top 3 and removes the timestamp.

Comment: I really like this solution. You didn't even use a FOR loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers feel very complicated, how about

for FILE in `find . -type d`; do ls -t -1 -F $FILE | grep -v "/" | head -n3 | xargs -I{} mv {} ..; done;

or laid out nicely

```
  for FILE in `find . -type d`; 
  do
      ls -t -1 -F $FILE | grep -v "/" | grep "^2010" | head -n3 | xargs -I{} mv {} ~;
  done;
```

Answer (score 0):

My "shortest" answer after quickly hacking it up.

```
for file in $(find . -iname *.php -mtime 1 | xargs ls -l | awk '{ print $6" "$7" "$8" "$9 }' | sort | sed -n '1,3p' | awk '{ print $4 }'); do cp $file ../; done
```

The main command stored in `$()` does the following:

1. `Find` all files recursively in current directory matching (case insensitive) the name *.php and having been modified in the last 24 hours.
2. Pipe to `ls -l`, required to be able to sort by modification date, so we can have the first three
3. Extract the modification date and file name/path with `awk`
4. `Sort` these files based on datetime
5. With `sed` print only the first 3 files
6. With `awk` print only their name/path
7. Used in a for loop and as action copy them to the desired location.

Or use @Hasturkun's variant, which popped as a response while I was editing this post :)